# Where/how to store frequently updated data feeding shiny apps?

Tags: shiny, dataset, storage

I built a shiny app which works with data that needs frequent update. The app doesn't change, just the data. At the beginning, i used to update my data locally, and republish my app every time the data had been updated, which i quickly found quite annoying.
I then started to store my datasets online (on arcgis online, for various reasons) so that i wouldn't need to republish my shiny app anymore, just need to handle the process of data updates.
The problem is that my app is quite slow as the datasets are very big.
Now i would like to transform my datasets as api's so that the requests coming from shiny could be more targeted.
But i don't know really know to do that. Handling the update of datasets on arcgis online through an R script was fine. But updating the same datasets as hosted feature service, i can't make it work.
Would anyone have an idea?
Or more general question, if moving away from my Arcgis online storage, what would be the best way to store data that needs frequent updates and that feed shiny apps?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into caching data using 'Pins' package